Illuminate\Database\QueryException in laravel artisan for migrate
I try migrate install and installed but I took this error
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table Takran.requests(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter tablerequestsadd constraintrequests_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references users (id`))
at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:822 818▕ $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e 819▕ ); 820▕ } 821▕ ➜ 822▕ throw new QueryException( 823▕ $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e 824▕ ); 825▕ } 826▕ }`

Please include your migration fields for Takran.requests and tablerequestsadd tables
